# How do I set up the defualt page icon for admin menu?

Tags: admin, icon

What do i Change this to So its shows the default page icon?`', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' )`

```
 add_menu_page( 'Info', 'Info', 'manage_options', 'LINK', '', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 10 );
```

I find out how to do this.

Step 1. Screenshot or find the image you like.

Step 2. Name it icon.png

step 3. Create a folder myplugin inside the plugin folder and then create inside that folder images folder and then put the icon.png image inside the image folder and thats it.

in short plugin > myplugin > image > icon.png

Comment: download  default page icon then set using page_menu_page function.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84200/how-to-change-default-icon-of-custom-plugin

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you're running WP 3.8, you can choose from a collection of icons ([listed here](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/)). In your case, replace your icon URL with `dashicons-admin-page`, like so:

```
 add_menu_page( 'Info', 'Info', 'manage_options', 'LINK', '', 'dashicons-admin-page', 10 );
```

You can use these icons in various places around WP. There are various articles on this like [this one](http://jameskoster.co.uk/work/using-wordpress-3-8s-dashicons-theme-plugin/).

Comment: I need the default page icon. Not a new icon.

Comment: @user1355485 The admin menu uses Dashicons, so this should be the default icon for the Pages menu item. I hope you are trying the example first. If that's not the icon you're looking for, you may need to elaborate on what you mean by default or by page.

Comment: OP - @helenhousandi is right. My suggestion should work and the link to the Dashicons repository is what Wordpress uses for all the WP-Admin icons.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability,
 $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); ?> 


<?php  add_menu_page( 'My Page Title', 'My Page', 'edit_others_posts',
 'my_page_slug', 'my_page_function', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 6 );  ?>
```

[moreinfo:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

Comment: Please add some details what this code block is and how it's functioning, then paste the code and link for further details. It's to make the answer more informative rather a simple code block. Thnaks.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus#Sub-Menus

Comment: Edit the answer and add details. Please don't misuse the comment area.